# Grafana Dashboard not displaying pod name

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have deployed grafana on Kubernetes. I have set up Prometheus as a data source. Everything is ok except the dashboard. Pod name isn't being displayed, instead it displays a name `pod_name`. I expected it to display the actual name of the pod. See attached screenshot.

Here is the query:
`sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}[1m])) by (pod_name)`[image]

Comment: What's the graph settings look like? You're grouping by pod name. Are you sure this label is present in the prometheus query?

Comment: @Dandy I am using this dashboard -> https://github.com/Thakurvaibhav/k8s/blob/master/monitoring/dashboards/Kubernetes%20cluster%20monitoring%20(via%20Prometheus).json

Comment: prometheus settings https://www.codepile.net/pile/7kVKG5ml

Comment: @learner While trying to diagnose your problem, I went through some of the default dashboards provided by Grafana. I can see the same problem as you have mentioned in some of the dashboards. It looks like its an error on their side and will probably be fixed soon. You can open an issue on their GitHub page.